# Numbering of sections, subsections, subsections, and all theorem-like environments in the dictionary order

Tags: sectioning, numbering, theorems, ieeetran, amsthm

I would like the numbering of sections, subsections, subsections, and all theorem-like environments to be in the strict dictionary order. Moreover, the number of a theorem-like environment contained in

- section X should start with X.
- subsection X.Y should start with X.Y.
- subsubsection X.Y.Z should start with X.Y.Z.

Moreover, we do not want useless zeros, i.e., for all X,Y,Z,

- if 0.X occurs, then 1 also occurs (perhaps, as a prefix of some 1...),
- if X.0.Y occurs, then X.1 also occurs (perhaps, as a prefix of some X.1...),
- if X.Y.0.Z occurs, then X.Y.1 also occurs (perhaps, as a prefix of some X.Y.1...).

One can view removing useless zeros algorithmically as, say, transforming all 0.X to X until saturation, then all X.0.Y to X.Y until saturation, then all X.Y.0.Z to X.Y.Z until saturation. (This is an algorithm for a human, not for TeX.)

Furthermore, the number of a first theorem-like environment right after the most recent \section, \subsection, or a \subsubsection should finish with a 1.

I am using the IEEEtran class with amsthm and cleveref packages.

AMS FAQ mentions only partial, nonautomatic solutions involving several theorem-like environments for, say, "Theorem". There was a partial solution for the book class some time ago on comp.text.tex. Is there an automatic one for IEEEtran & amsthm & cleveref? Is there, perhaps, a replacement for amsthm that does the job?

An MWE is attached.

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ifxetexorluatex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},%backref=section,
 colorlinks=false,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[nosort]{cleveref}% nosort just for the purpose of debugging
\usepackage{mathtools}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[subsection]
\newtheorem{exmp}[defn]{Example}
\newtheorem*{exmp*}{Example}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{lem}[defn]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[defn]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{thm}[defn]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corl}[defn]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{note}[defn]{Note}

\crefname{section}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefname{subsection}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefname{subsubsection}{\S}{\S\S}
\crefformat{section}{\S\,#2#1#3}
\crefformat{subsection}{\S\,#2#1#3}
\crefformat{subsubsection}{\S\,#2#1#3}
\crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{defn}{Def.}{Defs.}
\Crefname{defn}{Def.}{Defs.}
\crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\Crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.}
\Crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.}
\crefname{exmp}{Example}{Examples}
\Crefname{exmp}{Example}{Examples}
\crefname{prop}{Prop.}{Props.}
\Crefname{prop}{Prop.}{Props.}
\crefname{corl}{Cor.}{Cors.}
\Crefname{corl}{Cor.}{Cors.}
\crefname{enumi}{part}{parts}
\Crefname{enumi}{Part}{Parts}

\begin{document}
Introduction
\begin{defn}\label{ZO}Want the number 0.1 here.\end{defn}
\section{Initial Section}
\begin{exmp}\label{OZO}Want the number 1.0.1 here.\end{exmp}
\begin{lem}\label{OZT}Want the number 1.0.2 here.\end{lem}
\subsection{Initial Subsection}
\begin{exmp*}Want no number here.\end{exmp*}
\begin{prop}\label{OOO}Want number 1.1.1 here.\end{prop}
\begin{thm}\label{OOT}Want number 1.1.2 here.\end{thm}
\subsection{Another Subsection}
\begin{corl}\label{OTO}Want number 1.2.1 here.\end{corl}
\begin{note}\label{OTT}Want number 1.2.2 here.\end{note}

\section{Another section}
\begin{defn}\label{TZO}Want number 2.0.1 here.\end{defn}
\begin{exmp}\label{TZT}Want number 2.0.2 here.\end{exmp}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\begin{lem}\label{TOZO}Want number 2.1.0.1 here.\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{TOZT}Want number 2.1.0.2 here.\end{prop}
\subsubsection{Some subsubsection}
\begin{thm}\label{TOOO}Want number 2.1.1.1 here.\end{thm}
\begin{corl}\label{TOOT}Want number 2.1.1.2 here.\end{corl}
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\begin{note}\label{TOTO}Want number 2.1.2.1 here.\end{note}
\begin{defn}\label{TOTT}Want number 2.1.2.2 here.\end{defn}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\begin{exmp}\label{TTZO}Want number 2.2.0.1 here.\end{exmp}
\begin{lem}\label{TTZT}Want number 2.2.0.2 here.\end{lem}
\subsubsection{Some subsubsection}
\begin{prop}\label{TTOO}Want number 2.2.1.1 here.\end{prop}
\begin{thm}\label{TTOT}Want number 2.2.1.2 here.\end{thm}
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\begin{corl}\label{TTTO}Want number 2.2.2.1 here.\end{corl}
\begin{note}\label{TTTT}Want number 2.2.2.2 here.\end{note}

\appendices
\section{Some appendix}
\begin{defn}\label{AZO}Want number A.0.1 here.\end{defn}
\begin{exmp}\label{AZT}Want number A.0.2 here.\end{exmp}
\subsection{Some subsubsection}
\begin{lem}\label{AOO}Want number A.1.1 here.\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{AOT}Want number A.1.2 here.\end{prop}
\subsection{Another subsubsection}
\begin{thm}\label{ATO}Want number A.2.1 here.\end{thm}
\begin{corl}\label{ATT}Want number A.2.2 here.\end{corl}

\section{Another appendix}
\begin{note}\label{BZO}Want number B.0.1 here.\end{note}
\begin{defn}\label{BZT}Want number B.0.2 here.\end{defn}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\begin{exmp}\label{BOZO}Want number B.1.0.1 here.\end{exmp}
\begin{lem}\label{BOZT}Want number B.1.0.2 here.\end{lem}
\subsubsection{Some subsubsection}
\begin{prop}\label{BOOO}Want number B.1.1.1 here.\end{prop}
\begin{thm}\label{BOOT}Want number B.1.1.2 here.\end{thm}
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\begin{corl}\label{BOTO}Want number B.1.2.1 here.\end{corl}
\begin{note}\label{BOTT}Want number B.1.2.2 here.\end{note}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\begin{defn}\label{BTZO}Want number B.2.0.1 here.\end{defn}
\begin{exmp}\label{BTZT}Want number B.2.0.2 here.\end{exmp}
\subsubsection{Some subsubsection}
\begin{lem}\label{BTOO}Want number B.2.1.1 here.\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{BTOT}Want number B.2.1.2 here.\end{prop}
\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\begin{thm}\label{BTTO}Want number B.2.2.1 here.\end{thm}
\begin{corl}\label{BTTT}Want number B.2.2.2 here.\end{corl}

And now let us reference them all:

\Cref{ZO,OZO,OZT,OOO,OOT,OTO,OTT,TZO,TZT,TOZO,TOZT,TOOO,TOOT,TOTO,TOTT,TTZO,TTZT,TTOO,TTOT,TTTO,TTTT,AZO,AZT,AOO,AOT,ATO,ATT,BZO,BZT,BOZO,BOZT,BOOO,BOOT,BOTO,BOTT,BTZO,BTZT,BTOO,BTOT,BTTO,BTTT}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the reference to `BZZO` and `BZZT` be B.0.1 and B.0.2, respectively?

Comment: I don't understand the reference to "we don't want useless zeros" and how you're "fixing" them. How do you want to also make sure that a "1" occurs?

Comment: You are right, BZZO, BZZT should be BZO and BZT. I am currently editing my question to better address your question.

Comment: regarding your requirement that the first theorem-class object at any sectioning level must end with 1 (rather than continue on from the previous (sub)section) is a known weakness with amsthm, and is on the list to investigate, although this is more properly associated with document class.  however, it is impossible to know automatically the number of levels that can apply in a document; some indication *must* be given if there is a change of the lowest level.

Comment: @barbara-beeton: One can write the information about the lowest level to the aux file and analyze it on the second pass. I don't know how to do it technically.

Comment: @PetrosTravioli -- yes, that could be done, but how it's done might very well differ by document class.  even if it is not, it would almost certainly require a major rethinking and reworking of `amsthm`, which is nontrivial.  `amsthm` is rather tightly associated with ams document classes, but there already exist non-ams packages that load it in and make incompatible modifications; ams can't be responsible for those.

Comment: @barbara-beeton: I would be happy with another theorem package instead of amsthm. (ntheorem is out of scope: it has inacceptable bugs in the qed placement.)

Comment: @PetrosTravioli -- full disclosure: i'm on the technical support staff of ams, who are responsible for the ams packages.  so my bias is toward the tools with which i am most familiar.  at least you didn't say that the qed handling in `amsthm` was seriously buggy or lacking necessary features; many other people *have* registered such complaints.

Comment: @barabra-beeton: I see. I did not mean to hurt anybody; thanks for letting me know. 
Back to the question: since you are on the support stuff, has anybody solved _parts_ of the above problem for IEEEtran similar to, say, 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.text.tex/how$20to$20let$20theorem$20numbering$20follow$20%28sub-%29sections/comp.text.tex/qQRQx03O-I8/8rl_vBgljjgJ
for book?

Comment: @PetrosTravioli: I don't understand the numbering you present *at all*. For example, why should `OOO` be `1.1.1` while `TOZO` be `2.1.0.1`. These are "theorem-like" environment *at the same* level, yet they have different structures in their numbering. So, please explain what the structure of the of the numbering means more clearly.

Comment: @Werner: O=One=1, T=Two=2, Z=Zero=0. So, OOO=OneOneOne=111, TOZO=TwoOneZeroOne=2101.

Comment: @Werner: The example has no 3, so there is no ambiguity.
The high-level idea is to have a really common numbering of sections, subsections, subsubsections, and theorem-like environments. Moreover, one should avoid zeros without need: if section 1 has no subsubsections, the number 1.0.0.1 is strange and consumes too much space, since the third digit will remain 0 for all theorems in section 1.

Comment: @PetrosTravioli: I don't care about the mapping of characters to numbers that you use. I still don't know why you use 3 levels A.B.C for the label OOO yet 4 levels A.B.C.D for the label TOZO even though they are at the same sectional level - just under subsection.

Comment: @Werner: If we would use, say, 2.1.1 for TOZO instead of 2.1.0.1, then this number would clash with the subsubsection number 2.1.1. This would violate the dictionary order requirement. The zero in 2.1.0.1 signifies that the corresponding lemma is before the first subsubsection 2.1.1, and that this subsubsection will occur.

I'm going to add the requirement that the dictionary order should be strict.

Comment: After pondering, one can produce an even better visible structure. Namely, one could distinguish numbers of theorem-like environments from numbers of section-like environments by turning the last portion of theorem-like environments into greek letters (assuming that there will be no more than 24 of them per sectioning element). Or keeping the arabic letters but changing the last point into a colon. Say, lemma 2.1.0.1 would be then 2.1.0.α or 2.1.0:1 or 2.1.0:α. To be frank, one should try these suggestions out to see what is visually better. Any ideas from your sides on the better design?

Comment: Without some complicated writing to the aux file, I don't see how one could "look ahead" to check if e.g. subsection 2.1.1 occurs and thus number theorems starting in section 2 as 2.1.0.1, 2.1.0.2, etc.